# Getting a Whitelabel error page using SpringBoot and JSP

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jsp

I am using Spring Boot and MongoDB to run a JSP.  I am getting this error in my JSP, which I am calling welcome.jsp.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jan 29 15:35:40 PST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

This is in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is in EmployeeController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employees", getEmployees());
    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping("/getEmployees")
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    MongoDatabase db = getDatabase();
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection(COLLECTION);
    Document query = new Document();
    List<Employee> employees = collection.find(query, Employee.class).into(new ArrayList<Employee>());
    return employees;
}
```

Comment: Is your welcome page directly inside `/WEB-INF/` or is inside a sub level of it? Maybe if you could add your folder structure.

Comment: Yes, my welcome page is directly inside `/WEB-INF/`.

Comment: What's the URL you are trying to access? `localhost:8080/`

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/welcome`

Comment: That seems to be the problem. You mapped the welcome page to `localhost:8080/`, if you want to use `http://localhost:8080/welcome`, you will need to change your controller. `@RequestMapping("/welcome")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alain Cruz for suggesting I change the `@RequestMapping()` to `@RequestMapping("welcome")`

Comment: Glad I was of help :)